# Executing Prometheus Queries using Command line interface / linux environment

Tags: prometheus

I want to execute the Prometheus Queries in the linux environment using PromQl, is it possible to achieve this , if so could someone share the solution for executing the promql queries in linux environment.
Does Prometheus has its own CLI?

Comment: This definitely can be done with [`promtool query`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/command-line/promtool/#promtool-query). Http config is [not described anywhere yet](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/12924), so some trial and error might be need to figure everything out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Prometheus does have its own CLI. Actually Prometheus itself is a binary which can be configured both from configuration files and through CLI arguments. [Here](https://prometheus.io/download/#prometheus) you can download the CLI.

To perform queries you can use another CLI provided by Prometheus project: [promtool](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/command-line/promtool/#promtool-query)

But, you can also use `curl`. Example of query using `curl` in a linux command:

```
curl -G --data-urlencode 'query=rate(http_requests_total[5m])' http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query | jq .
```

With `-G`, curl appends the data as query string parameters to the URL and sends a GET request.